# There is a way to abbreviate react props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Hi there I have a lot of react components looking like:

`<MyComponent content={content} />`

I'm looking for some kind of writing the same but abbreviated, now that if I only add `content` prop that means `content` it's `true` but in my case I want to pass an object.

Regards.

Comment: reactjs supports props spreads just a FYI. But not an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: Yeah I now, would be usefull if all props I have to pass belongs to same object

Comment: do you need something like defaultProps? So by default content can be have a specific value but you can also change it?

Comment: @needsleep .. no the OP wants some kind of shortcut to add props to the component.. what is available for `checked`, `disabled` props for example'

Comment: what's stopping you from abbreviating it `c={c}` or am I not getting the question

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky when you write say `const c = 1;` and then `const obj = {c}`, it expands to `{c: 1}`, The OP wants similar thing in React JS props passing which is not possible IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread operator, like so:

```
<MyComponent {...props} />
```

Comment: this is not what the OP asked.

Comment: How it got so many upvotes, while this didn't answer the actual question at all? The only direct answer to the question is that _no it is not possible_ for now.

Comment: @arup well actually if you spread an object literal this saves the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Adam 's answer.

You can define your properties as a const;

```
const content = // some code;
const myProps = {
    content
};
```

Notice that if I have a property which matches the property on the component, then you can just do it that way. Otherwise you can create it as;

```
const otherProperty ...
const myProps = {
    content: otherProperty
}
```

Then using "Spread syntax" apply the properties to the component;

```
<MyComponent {...myProps} />
```

Comment: defining the `content` and then creating an object `myProps` to use **props spread** is too much, instead of writing `content={content}` .. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit well not many options so this is one way :) Sometimes doing what you want requires writing more code than it would take to do it the other way. :)

Comment: @espascarello if done right this can actually save 3 chars :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeah in this instance it is major overkill, however it is a way for building up a more complex object for future use.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned that can be shortened a bit with the spread operator:

```
 <MyComponent {...{content}} />
```